# Download of 16.04 LTS not possible - Laptop HP Pavilion with Windows 10

Tags: macosx, transfer

first I have to explain the following:
1) My English is poor, I'm German
2) I'm a 'greenhorn' in doing installationson a computer
3) I'm using also a MacBook Pro with OSX 10.6.8
The problem: 
I hate Windows, but a lot of downloads or CDs/DVDs, e.g. for my SAT NAV etc. are not running on Mac. So I bought a used HP Pavilion with Win8, what is upgraded (cost free test version) with Win10 till July. Now I want to exchange against Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Problem: The download stopped after about half an hour, telling there wouldn't be enough space to finish (there is enough space of course, but may be, I made a mistake - wanted to save and to burn a CD afterwards).
My query:
Is it possible to do the download for the HP with Win10 on my MacBook, to burn a CD from there and to make the installation using this CD on the HP then?
Many thanks in advance 
Avon35

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will be. The CD will work on any device as long as you have selected the correct version of Ubuntu for your processor.

(Intel, AMD) etc..

Answer (score 0):

The following helped me install Ubuntu 16.04 on my msi CX61 2PC with Windows 10 installed. 
[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

I now can dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 with Secure Boot enabled.